# Convert a sub-selection of a result set in T-SQL into JSON using "for json auto"

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a trigger that fires on insert to my table. I want to be able to serialize each row in the `inserted` result set and insert it as a "JsonValue" column in another table, as well as some other values into a new table. Currently the trigger looks something like this:

```
create trigger dbo.InsertContactAudit
on Contact
   after insert
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    insert into ContactAudit (
        JsonMessage, EventType, ContactId, ProjectId, CorrelationId
    )
    select 'entire row serialized to json', 'create', inserted.ContactId, inserted.ProjectId, inserted.CorrelationId
    from Contact inserted;
```

The piece I am having trouble with is the `'entire row to json here'`. In a similar situation I could do something like:

```
select column1, column2, column3 from table for json auto;
```

and that would give me something similar to `{ "column1": "value 1", "column2", "value2", ... }`

Is there a way to get the behavior I want? Serialize a whole row into json while still inserting into other columns, within the trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you want to use `JSON AUTO`?

To achieve the JSON format you're asking for, with the set of columns for each row in its own JSON blob without the surrounding `[]` characters, you could do something like this...

```sql
use master
go
if exists(select * from sys.databases where name='StackOverflow')
    drop database StackOverflow
go
create database StackOverflow
go
use StackOverflow;
create table dbo.Contact (
    ContactId int not null identity,
    ProjectId int,
    CorrelationId int,
    Column1 nvarchar(20),
    Column2 nvarchar(20),
    Column3 nvarchar(20)
);
create table dbo.ContactAudit (
    JsonMessage nvarchar(max),
    EventType nvarchar(20),
    ContactId int not null,
    ProjectId int,
    CorrelationId int
);
go
create trigger dbo.InsertContactAudit on dbo.Contact
after insert as
begin
    set nocount on;
    insert into dbo.ContactAudit (JsonMessage, EventType, ContactId, ProjectId, CorrelationId)
        select (
        select ContactId, ProjectId, CorrelationId, Column1, Column2, Column3
        for json path, without_array_wrapper
        ), 'create', ContactId, ProjectId, CorrelationId
        from inserted;
end
go
insert Contact (ProjectId, CorrelationId, Column1, Column2, Column3)
    values (null, null, null, null, null);
insert Contact (ProjectId, CorrelationId, Column1, Column2, Column3)
    values (1, 2, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz');
select * from dbo.ContactAudit;
go
```

Which would record the following into dbo.ContactAudit...

```
JsonMessage                                                                                     EventType            ContactId   ProjectId   CorrelationId
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- -------------
{"ContactId":1}                                                                                 create               1           NULL        NULL
{"ContactId":2,"ProjectId":1,"CorrelationId":2,"Column1":"Foo","Column2":"Bar","Column3":"Baz"} create               2           1           2
```